# .Net Core App in Openshift linux Pod connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux, .net-core, openshift

I have a .net Core Rest Service deployed in OpenShift which connects to an External SQL Server. I have added the Host Name in the configuration for my namespace. I also have Kerberos setup in a side car

I still have connection errors

my connection string is as follows

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlDbContext": "Server=ServerXYZ\\InstanceXYZ,55001;Database=myAppDB;Integrated Security=True;
  }
```

The error I get is

> “SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
> while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
> found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
> and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections
>
> ”

When I run the api from my local windows PC iw works fine, but I am not sure if I need to adapt the connection string for the OpenShift Linux pod

Comment: You have both an instance name and a port number in your connection string. Prefer to specify just the port number when known. When an instance name is specified the SQL Browser service must be running on the target server, and accessible via udp/1434, to resolve the instance name to a TCP port number that the client software can then connect to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So add it like this? ServerXYZ,55001 or ServerXYZ\\55001 or ServerXYZ:55001

Comment: Use ServerNameOrIpAddress,PortNumber

Comment: Unfortunately as of now with my limited knowledge , you can't connect to sql server via openshift or any Linux based machines because your application has to run in windows mode which is not possible in Linux world. Next Kerberos is the way but until .net 3.1 this isn't supported

Comment: Revisit - it’s possible and can be done in .net core 3.0 and above using Kerberos keytabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the full domain name of the SQL Server myserver.mydomain.com